# Why is there a Text Search tab in the local instance admin console?

Tags: google-app-engine, search

As I understand it the Text Search (retrospective not predictive) API is not out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTS is currently in trusted tester phase, you can sign up [here](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEdWcnRJUXZ2VGR3YmVsT1Q1WVB2Smc6MQ&ndplr=1) if interested.

Comment: Thanks, signed up using the link you provided. Do you know how they make their decision to let you into the program?

Comment: The engineering team responsible of the program usually enroll people by batches each week.